# Python class attribute is shared by all instances. How to avoid it?

Tags: python

I have a `Node` class. Its `addAllNodes` method reads items from a tree and adds them into `all_nodes` list. For each tree I want to have a unique `all_nodes`.

```
d1= [{'id':1,  'name':'one',   'children_id':[2, 3, 4]},
     {'id':2,  'name':'two',   'children_id':[5, 6]},
     {'id':3,  'name':'three', 'children_id':[7]},
     {'id':4,  'name':'four',  'children_id':[8,9]},
     {'id':5,  'name':'five',  'children_id':[]},
     {'id':6,  'name':'six',   'children_id':[10]},
     {'id':7,  'name':'seven', 'children_id':[]},
     {'id':8,  'name':'eight', 'children_id':[11]},
     {'id':9,  'name':'nine',  'children_id':[]},
     {'id':10, 'name':'ten',   'children_id':[]},
     {'id':11, 'name':'eleven',   'children_id':[]} 
]


d2= [{'id':1,  'name':'one',   'children_id':[2, 3]},
     {'id':2,  'name':'two',   'children_id':[5, 6]},
     
]
class Node():

    all_nodes=[]
    
    def __init__(self, d):
        '''d is a dictionary with keys: id, name and children'''
        self.children =[] #list of Nodes
        self.data=d      

    def addNodes(self):            
        for i in self.data['children_id']:
            d=next(item for item in d1 if item['id']==i)
            node=Node(d)
            self.children.append(node)

    def addAllNodes(self):
        
        #if the Node is a leaf
        if not self.data['children_id']:
            self.all_nodes.append(self.data['id'])
            return 
        self.addNodes()
        self.all_nodes.append(self.data['id'])
        for n in self.children:
            n.addAllNodes()
            

  
    
n=Node(d1[0])
n.addAllNodes()
print(n.all_nodes)

k=Node(d2[0])
k.addAllNodes()   
print(k.all_nodes)
print(n.all_nodes)
```

When I have only one `Node` instance it works as I expect. For 2 instances it breaks and gives some unexpected results, i.e. far more items than there are in `d2`. It has even more items than concatenation of the 2 expected lists. 
What is my mistake? How can this code be fixed?

Comment: `all_nodes`, as a class attribute, is shared *by design*. It should probably be an instance attribute like `children` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don’t think `all_nodes` needs to be a class attribute. You could try this:

```py
d1 = [
    {"id": 1, "name": "one", "children_id": [2, 3, 4]},
    {"id": 2, "name": "two", "children_id": [5, 6]},
    {"id": 3, "name": "three", "children_id": [7]},
    {"id": 4, "name": "four", "children_id": [8, 9]},
    {"id": 5, "name": "five", "children_id": []},
    {"id": 6, "name": "six", "children_id": [10]},
    {"id": 7, "name": "seven", "children_id": []},
    {"id": 8, "name": "eight", "children_id": [11]},
    {"id": 9, "name": "nine", "children_id": []},
    {"id": 10, "name": "ten", "children_id": []},
    {"id": 11, "name": "eleven", "children_id": []},
]


d2 = [
    {"id": 1, "name": "one", "children_id": [2, 3]},
    {"id": 2, "name": "two", "children_id": [5, 6]},
    {"id": 3, "name": "three", "children_id": []},
    {"id": 5, "name": "five", "children_id": []},
    {"id": 6, "name": "six", "children_id": []},
]


class Node:
    def __init__(self, d, all_data):
        """d is a dictionary with keys: id, name and children."""
        self.children = []  # list of Nodes
        self.data = d
        self.all_nodes = []
        self.all_data = all_data

    def addNodes(self):
        for i in self.data["children_id"]:
            d = next(item for item in self.all_data if item["id"] == i)
            self.children.append(Node(d, self.all_data))

    def addAllNodes(self):
        self.addNodes()
        self.all_nodes.append(self.data["id"])
        for n in self.children:
            self.all_nodes += n.addAllNodes()
        return self.all_nodes


n = Node(d1[0], d1)
n.addAllNodes()
print(n.all_nodes)

k = Node(d2[0], d2)
k.addAllNodes()
print(k.all_nodes)
print(n.all_nodes)
```

I’ve filled in the missing `d2` entries so it doesn’t crash.

Comment: Edited; I think it does what you want now.

Comment: This is much better now. Thank you. However, it gives additional `7` as the last item of the second list. It seems to me that  it gets this `7` from the `d1`. Does it?

Comment: `d1` is hard-coded into the definition of `addNodes`. I noticed that the children in `d2` are not in `d2` (3, 5 and 6), so trying to fix this produces an error.

Comment: I made `children_id` list of the 2nd item empty. It stil brings 5, 6 and 7. Still incorrect :(

Comment: Thank you very much! I did something wrong previously :)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to add a separate Tree class that holds all_nodes, and have Nodes have A reference to their respective Tree.

Comment: Can you please give more details? What Tree class should do?